# Gps location in android

Tags: android

I am using LocationManager to get the current location in android.for that ,i have used

```
 mlocManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 0, 0, mlocListener);
```

GPS_PROVIDER as a service provide.while executing  it returns null and shows the following in the log cat continuously.

**V/libgps  (  116): DeferredActionThread pthread_cond_wait returned**

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you implemented the LocationListener in the class??

Comment: yes ofcourse.when i user Network_Provider instead of GPS_PROVIDER it works well.but why it is not working with GPS_PROVIDER.

Comment: you should have tested it on Real Mobile?? with GPS ON..! r u testing it on Emulator?

Comment: i am testing on htc desire-with Gps On.\

Comment: ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION permission added?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
public class HomeActivity extends Activity implements LocationListener{
public static Context mContext;
private double latitude, longitude;
 public LocationManager mLocManager;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    mContext=this;
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.homelayout);


    mLocManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);

    mLocManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 0, 0,
            this);
    mLocManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER, 0,
            0, this);
    locationUpdate();
    ((Button) this.findViewById(R.id.ButtonHome))
            .setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(View arg0) {

                        startActivity(new Intent(HomeActivity.this,
                                DefaultDisplay.class));

                }
            });

    ((Button) this.findViewById(R.id.ButtonProfile))
            .setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

                public void onClick(View arg0) {
                    if (GUIStatics.boolLoginStatus) {
                        startActivity(new Intent(HomeActivity.this,
                                MyProfile.class));
                    } else {
                        Intent intent=new Intent(HomeActivity.this,
                                Login.class);
                        intent.putExtra("moveTo","MyProfile");
                        startActivity(intent);
                    }
                }
            });

    ((Button) this.findViewById(R.id.ButtonNotifications))
            .setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

                public void onClick(View arg0) {
                    if (GUIStatics.boolLoginStatus) {
                        startActivity(new Intent(HomeActivity.this,
                                ShowAllNotificationActiviry.class));
                    } else {
                        Intent intent=new Intent(HomeActivity.this,
                                Login.class);
                        intent.putExtra("moveTo","ShowAllNotificationActiviry");
                        startActivity(intent);
                    }
                }
            });

    ((Button) this.findViewById(R.id.ButtonFavorites))
            .setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

                public void onClick(View arg0) {
                    if (GUIStatics.boolLoginStatus) {
                        startActivity(new Intent(HomeActivity.this,
                                FavoritesActivity.class));
                    } else {
                        Intent intent=new Intent(HomeActivity.this,
                                Login.class);
                        intent.putExtra("moveTo","FavoritesActivity");
                        startActivity(intent);
                    }
                }
            });

            ((Button) this.findViewById(R.id.ButtonMore))
            .setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(View arg0) {
                        startActivity(new Intent(HomeActivity.this,
                                MoreListActivity.class));
                }
            });

}

public void locationUpdate()
{
    CellLocation.requestLocationUpdate();
}


public void getAddress(double lat, double lng) {
    Geocoder geocoder = new Geocoder(HomeActivity.mContext, Locale.getDefault());
    try {
        List<Address> addresses = geocoder.getFromLocation(lat, lng, 1);
        Address obj = addresses.get(0);
        String add = obj.getAddressLine(0);
        GUIStatics.currentAddress = obj.getSubAdminArea() + ","
                + obj.getAdminArea();
        GUIStatics.latitude = obj.getLatitude();
        GUIStatics.longitude = obj.getLongitude();
        GUIStatics.currentCity= obj.getSubAdminArea();
        GUIStatics.currentState= obj.getAdminArea();
        add = add + "\n" + obj.getCountryName();
        add = add + "\n" + obj.getCountryCode();
        add = add + "\n" + obj.getAdminArea();
        add = add + "\n" + obj.getPostalCode();
        add = add + "\n" + obj.getSubAdminArea();
        add = add + "\n" + obj.getLocality();
        add = add + "\n" + obj.getSubThoroughfare();

        Log.v("IGA", "Address" + add);
        // Toast.makeText(this, "Address=>" + add,
        // Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        // TennisAppActivity.showDialog(add);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
        Toast.makeText(this, e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}



public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
    latitude = location.getLatitude();
    longitude = location.getLongitude();
    GUIStatics.latitude=location.getLatitude();
    GUIStatics.longitude= location.getLongitude();
    Log.v("Test", "IGA" + "Lat" + latitude + "   Lng" + longitude);
    //mLocManager.r

    getAddress(latitude, longitude);
    if(location!=null)
    {

    mLocManager.removeUpdates(this);
    }
    // Toast.makeText(this, "Lat" + latitude + "   Lng" + longitude,
    // Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}


public void onProviderDisabled(String arg0) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    Toast.makeText(HomeActivity.this, "Gps Disabled", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    Intent intent = new Intent(
            android.provider.Settings.ACTION_LOCATION_SOURCE_SETTINGS);
    startActivity(intent);
}


public void onProviderEnabled(String arg0) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}


public void onStatusChanged(String arg0, int arg1, Bundle arg2) {
     if(arg1 == 
            LocationProvider.TEMPORARILY_UNAVAILABLE) { 
                                    Toast.makeText(HomeActivity.this, 
            "LocationProvider.TEMPORARILY_UNAVAILABLE", 
            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show(); 
                        } 
                        else if(arg1== LocationProvider.OUT_OF_SERVICE) { 
                                    Toast.makeText(HomeActivity.this, 
            "LocationProvider.OUT_OF_SERVICE", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show(); 
                        } 

}
```

}

I am using this code for getting latitude and longitude of current location of the user.
You should read it then convert it according to your requirement and also add the permission of using GPS in manifast file of your project.It is.

`<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_GPS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />`

I hope this is very helpful to you.

Comment: @DynamicMind..It gives me the result.but the result(lat&long) not changing for atleast 100m when i tested in the real device.

Comment: mLocManager.removeUpdates(this); remove this from the code then you find it is update continue but it is take few second for updating the location from GPS.

Answer (score 0):

Test this Code and then Tel me if u have any Success!

```
LocationManager locationManager;
String context = Context.LOCATION_SERVICE;
locationManager = (LocationManager)getSystemService(context);
Criteria criteria = new Criteria();
criteria.setAccuracy(Criteria.ACCURACY_FINE);
criteria.setAltitudeRequired(false);
criteria.setBearingRequired(false);
criteria.setCostAllowed(true);
criteria.setPowerRequirement(Criteria.POWER_LOW);
String provider = locationManager.getBestProvider(criteria, true);

Location location = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(provider);

updateWithNewLocation(location);

locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(provider, 2000, 10,   
                                       locationListener);
}

private final LocationListener locationListener = new LocationListener() {
public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
  updateWithNewLocation(location);
}

public void onProviderDisabled(String provider){
  updateWithNewLocation(null);
}

public void onProviderEnabled(String provider){ }
public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, 
                            Bundle extras){ }
};
```

and use following Permissions:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
```

this ones Working fine on ma side.. you should try all this!